# Participial phrase separating main verbs

Tags: verbs, participles, present-participles, participial-phrases

Let's say you have the following sentence:

I stood there and wondered what to do next.

Now, let's say you insert a participial phrase after "there."

I stood there **looking at her** and wondered what to do next.

Does the verb "wondered" have to become part of the participial phrase (i.e., "wondering what to do next"), or can it remain "wondered"?

I stood there **looking** at her and **wondering** what to do next vs. I **stood** there looking at her and **wondered** what to do next.

Comment: They're both okay and say slightly different things.

Comment: Omitting the locative for clarity, 'I stood looking at her' displays what Collins Cobuild terms the 'phase' (sometimes the 'go shopping') construction: two simultaneous  situations/events. Although obviously containing extra semantic content, this is comparable to the continuous ('I **was** looking at her [&/as  I was standing]').  'Stand' and some other verbs license this usage, and the ing-form **may be coordinate** ('They sat eating and drinking at the table'). But equally, a phase construction may be followed by a coordinate predicate ('They [sat drinking] and [in due course fell asleep].'

Comment: If the verb 'wondered' should become part of the participial, the best way is to use, "I stood there looking at her and wondering what to do."